# How to use own ontology to classify dbpedia terms extracted with stanbol?

Tags: nlp, ontology, owl, dbpedia, apache-stanbol

I am trying to build an application using Apache Stanbol which:

1. recognizes entities from DBpedia
2. classifies these entities using an OWL ontology which extends the definition of the `dcterms:subject` of these entities to correspond to my custom OWL class, `OwnClass`:

   ```xml
   <owl:Class rdf:ID="OwnClass">
   </owl:Class>  

   <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Branding">
     <rdf:type rdf:resource="#OwnClass"/>
   </rdf:Description>
   ```

So far I am able to extract the entities with their categories from DBpedia using the Stanbol Enhancer. But I cannot figure out where I have to integrate my ontology in order to classify these entities? My final goal is to have a JSON document reflecting the hierarchy: `OwnClass` ⇒ DBpedia category ⇒ entity. Is this possible with Stanbol and, if yes, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Use one of the [existing indices](http://dev.iks-project.eu/downloads/stanbol-indices/) in your configuration file:

```
# --- dbpedia specific
# the "dbp-ont" defines knowledge mapped to the DBPedia ontology
dbp-ont:*

#place typed properties
#dbp-ont:country
#dbp-ont:largestCity
#dbp-ont:city
#dbp-ont:state
#dbp-ont:capital
#dbp-ont:isPartOf
#dbp-ont:part
#dbp-ont:deathPlace
#dbp-ont:birthPlace
#dbp-ont:location

#person typed properties
#dbp-ont:leader
#dbp-ont:leaderName
#dbp-ont:child
#dbp-ont:spouse
#dbp-ont:partner
#dbp-ont:president

#organization typed properties
#dbp-ont:leaderParty
#dbp-ont:affiliation
#dbp-ont:team
#dbp-ont:otherParty
#dbp-ont:associatedBand

dbp-ont:birthDate | d=xsd:dateTime
dbp-ont:deathDate | d=xsd:dateTime
dbp-ont:populationTotal | d=xsd:long
dbp-ont:wikiPageExternalLink | d=xsd:anyURI
dbpedia-owl:areaTotal | d=xsd:double

# the "DBpedia properties are all key values pairs extracted from the info boxes
# on the right hand side of Wikipedia pages.
# Data Quality is to low to use them efficiently
#dbp-prop:*

# Copy only population for now (one could add additional if necessary)!
# use dbp-ont:populationTotal instead
# dbp-prop:population | d=xsd:long

#Deactivated mappings based on dbprops
#dbp-prop:latitude | d=xsd:double > geo:lat
#dbp-prop:longitude | d=xsd:double > geo:long
#dbp-prop:elevation | d=xsd:int;xsd:float > geo:alt
#dbp-prop:website | d=xsd:anyURI > foaf:homepage

dbp-prop:imageCaption
dbp-prop:region
dbp-prop:governor
dbp-prop:capital
dbp-prop:largestCity
dbp-prop:leaderName
dbp-prop:knownFor
dbp-prop:placeOfBirth
dbp-prop:workInstitutions
dbp-prop:caption
dbp-prop:shortDescription
```

Comment: which ttl file in dbpedia download has the #person typed properties?